# How to show filter result number in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working with a common Jquery filter, but It's not Showing total find or result number. I tried, but it showing wrong result. Another fact it when I clear the input field, it should clear the number too. Rather it showing more false number. Please look at my code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." tada-table="a">
<br><br>

<p id="search-result-num"></p>


<table class="a">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Aram</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mary</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@mail.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Anja</td>
    <td>Ravendale</td>
    <td>a_r@test.com</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<script type="text/javascript">

  $("input").on("keyup", function() {
    var valThis = this.value;

    $("table").find("tr td").each(function() {
      if ($(this).attr("data-search") !== "false") {
        var text = $(this).text();
        var textL = text.toLowerCase();
        var position = textL.indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase());

        var regex = new RegExp(valThis, "ig");
        text = text.replace(regex, (match, $1) => {
          // Return the replacement
          return "<mark>" + match + "</mark>";
        });


        /*This is what I'm trying to show */
        var num = text.length;
        $("#search-result-num").html(num);


        $(this).html(text);

        if (position !== -1) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(this).parent().find("mark").is(":empty")) {
              $("mark").remove();
            }
          }.bind(this), 0);
        } else {
          $(this).text(text);
        }
      }

      if ($(this).parent().find("mark").length > 0) {
        $(this).parent().show();
      } else {
        $(this).parent().hide();
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Why it not showing exact or correct result number ? And when I clear the input field, the number should clear. Rather it showing more wrong number.

Comment: Do you want it to show the visible rows or?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen No. When anyone search, it shows result with highlight. But I just want to show the match highlight number... How many number matched on filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to the end of your keyup function:

```
$("#search-result-num").text($('table tbody tr:visible').length);
```

This will count the visible rows in your table body.

Hope this is what your looking for.

**Demo**

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function() {
  var valThis = this.value;

  $('table').find('tr td').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-search') !== 'false') {
      var text = $(this).text();
      var textL = text.toLowerCase();
      var position = textL.indexOf(valThis.toLowerCase());

      var regex = new RegExp(valThis, 'ig');
      text = text.replace(regex, (match, $1) => {
        // Return the replacement
        return '<mark>' + match + '</mark>';
      });


      


      $(this).html(text);

      if (position !== -1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          if ($(this).parent().find('mark').is(':empty')) {
            $('mark').remove();
          }
        }.bind(this), 0);
      } else {
        $(this).text(text);
      }
    }

    if ($(this).parent().find('mark').length > 0) {
      $(this).parent().show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().hide();
    }
  });
  $("#search-result-num").text((valThis.length > 0 ? $('table tbody tr:visible mark').length : ""));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search.." tada-table="a">
<br><br>

<p id="search-result-num"></p>


<table class="a">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Aram</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Mary</td>
      <td>Moe</td>
      <td>mary@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>July</td>
      <td>Dooley</td>
      <td>july@greatstuff.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Anja</td>
      <td>Ravendale</td>
      <td>a_r@test.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, It's working. But when I clear the input field, a number stay always. It should be invisible.

Comment: Ans Please Brother

Comment: @Md.Ibrahim Please relax and keep in mind that we will answer when we have time. I've updated the demo, try it now

Comment: there's a problem. Its just counting row rumber, but not counting total find number. For example, when I enter A, it just showing "4" result number. But there's more than 4 number. I think it's jsut counting result row number. Not total matched number.

Comment: Now It's completely Perfect.